Issues with Lemon Sappling from seed
I started growing this lemon sappling from a seed a year ago and it doesn't look very healthy, also is it too small? Any tips?

Pot seems awfully small for a year-old tree unless you are going for Bonsai...

Are you aware that citrus fruit don't grow true to type?  ie the plant you are growing likely won't yield fruit that are anything like the parent?

Just looking, to me it seems either a problem of a disease, or some over fertilizing.

In my experience, citrus seedlings suffer from dry air when grown indoors, especially in cold season. And judging by the photo, the plant's mature leaves are drying out and falling off, but it is producing new healthy shoots. I would try spraying it with water periodically to see if this will keep leaves green and alive for longer.
